# PHP Script that searches & prints lines from file. How to avoid printing the same line?

Tags: php, file, search

I have a PHP file with different html info in every line, like for example:

```
0 <div><a href="post1.html">This post has keyword1 and keyword2</a></div>
1 </div><a href="post2.html">This post has keyword3 and keyword4</a></div>
2 </div><a href="post3.html">This post has keyword2 and keyword5</a></div>
```

Now I have a PHP Script that prints a line from this file when it finds the keyword I'm giving it through an array. This is the script:

```
<?php 
  $filename = 'post_file.php';
  $KEYWORDS_to_find = array("keyword1","keyword2");
  $i=0;
  foreach($KEYWORDS_to_find as $keyword){
     foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl){
       if($i>=5) break;
       if(stripos($fl, $keyword)!==false){ 
         echo $fl;
         $i++;
       }
     }
  }
?>
```

It starts searching "keyword1" in every line of post_file.php until the end. If "keyword1" is found, in this case in line 0, it prints the entire content of line 0. When it finishes with "keyword1", starts the same process with the second element or keyword of the array, in this case "keyword2". The script stops after printing 5 lines from the file.

The problem I'm trying to figure out is that it prints lines that were already printed. For example, "keyword2" exists in line 0 and line 2, so it prints line 0 twice as line 0 was already printed when searched for "keyword1". My question now is, what can I do to avoid  printing a line already printed?

Thanks, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Instead of iterate keywords first, you can iterate lines first, and on each line, checks if at least one keyword present.

Comment: I'd probably do the same as what @Passerby said. However, if for some reason, you wish to keep the order it is already in, you can introduce an array which keeps track of the line numbers already printed. You'd have to move the $i=0 so that it is inside foreach loop for the keywords for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work:

```
<?php

$filename = 'post_file.php';
$KEYWORDS_to_find = array("keyword1","keyword2");
$i=0;
$printed_lines = array(); //added this line
foreach($KEYWORDS_to_find as $keyword){
    foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl){
       if($i>=5) break;
       if(stripos($fl, $keyword)!==false){ 
        if(!in_array($fl,$printed_lines)) { //added this line
            $printed_lines[] = $fl; //added this line
            echo $fl;
            $i++;
        } //added this line
       }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Salim, unfortunately it didn't work, still repeating lines already printed.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake, it is corrected.
It should work now. try again please.

Comment: Cheers! it works now! before asking, I tried something similar saving the printed line in an array and then comparing it in the loop before it prints, but it didn't work in my way, now I know what was my mistake. Million thanks Salim.